# In PHP, how do I *safely* get locale information for a given locale?

Tags: php, locale, setlocale

I use PHP. Let's say I have Ireland's 2-letter ISO code, "IE". Now I want to grab all the locale info for IE, as an associative array. As far as I know, the only way is to run setlocale(), which according to this page is unsafe whenever threads are used (which they may or may not be on this or a future computer I will be using): https://www.php.net/setlocale

Since setlocale() is apparently required to be able to grab the locale data, is there any way to not SET the locale, but simply get the info? I'm trying to avoid having to find a data source for this and make my own database table and fill it up with data. I don't like the idea of being forced to use a database connection to get locale information in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what info you want.

Sometimes it's good enough to use public API, like [`restcountries.eu`](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/ie) via cURL

Comment: 1. I specifically said I wanted to avoid doing the "separate database table" thing. 2. Your link doesn't have any locale information... Which is another reason: it's impossible to find sane data.